# Is it possible to increase the electromagnetic repulsion between two particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, friction

Given the fact that the force stopping me falling through the ground is the electromagnetic repulsion between the electrons in my feet and the ground, would it be possible to increase this repulsive force? 
Also is friction generated due to this repulsion of angular faces at a very small scale ?
if so could a material be made so smooth it had zero friction because the electromagnetic force simply kept the two apart instead of causing friction?

Sorry if its a stupid question but im very interested to find out and why not if i am wrong.

Comment: "Also is friction generated due to this repulsion of angular faces at a very small scale ?" Yes.